# how to resolve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: packed field contains invalid sign

Tags: java, cobol

please go through the code... i have explained my problem within the code.

i have below COMP-3 variables

```
 //               PIC S9(03)  COMP-3.

protected static PackedDecimalAsBigDecimalField epcutb_org = factory.getPackedDecimalAsBigDecimalField(3, 0, true);

 //               PIC S9(03)  COMP-3.

protected static PackedDecimalAsBigDecimalField epcutb_curr = factory.getPackedDecimalAsBigDecimalField(3, 0, true);

//               PIC S9(06)  COMP-3.

protected static PackedDecimalAsBigDecimalField epcutb_org_curr = factory.getPackedDecimalAsBigDecimalField(6, 0, true);

public void setEpcutb_org(BigDecimal utb_org) { //utb_org==867

epcutb_org.putBigDecimal(utb_org ,epcutbytes);

 }

public void setEpcutb_curr(BigDecimal utb_curr) { // utb_curr=840

epcutb_curr.putBigDecimal(utb_curr ,epcutbytes);

 }


public BigDecimal getEpcutb_org_curr() { 

epcutb_org_curr.setOffset(epcutb_org.getOffset());  // here concatenation is happening for epcutb_org and epcutb_curr so the return value should be "867840" but the return value i am getting is "8682840"

return epcutb_org_curr.getBigDecimal(epcutbytes);
 }
```

please some one help me in understanding the issue and tell me whats wrong i am doing.

Comment: Can you share with us the values being read (obviously in hex because it is COMP-3).  My guess is that the last nibble (last 4 bits) isn't valid.

Comment: If I can guess: you likely using IBM libraries (you should explicit list what you're using) and try to resolve values that don't come from the Mainframe - in which case you may have to convert them before.

Comment: As Simon said: this question is missing relevant information: where does the data come from? What does it look like? What library are you using?